# Show / Hide DIV based on radio button selection in WHMCS / Bootstrap

Tags: jquery

I am running Bootstrap and WHMCS. And I have several multiple choice selections (radio buttons).

Depending on what multiple choice is selected, I want it to show a DIV (Boostrap alert-info) with additional information.

However I am running into a few problems. The label name is every time different. The only thing which is the same are the options (values).

Example:
What kind of anti-spam solution do you want to use

a) No anti-spam solution

b) Default anti-spam filters

If they would select option 'B' (Default anti-spam filters) the DIV would appear with additional information.

Due to limitations (and my own skill) it's impossible to target labels, right?

Here is an example of the HTML part:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputConfigOption14">
            <div>What kind of anti-spam solution do you want to use</div>
        </label>

        <label class="">
            <div class="iradio_square-blue" style="style="position: relative;">
                <input type="radio" value="43" name="configoption[14] style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></input>
            </div>
            No anti-spam solution
        </label>

        <label class="">
            <div class="iradio_square-blue" style="style="position: relative;">
                <input type="radio" value="43" name="configoption[14] style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></input>
            </div>
            Default anti-spam filters
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I also created a JSFiddle of the HTML [here](http://jsfiddle.net/07apbnoe/).

I think the easiest way, is to target the text value, so if it contains text value "Default anti-spam filters" it should display the DIV (and hide it again if a different option is selected).

Is this possible through jQuery? Or is there a better way, if so how?

----- Follow up ------

Thank you all for answering, but I cannot change the name of ID's or anything. That's why I have to target the value, for example: "Default anti-spam filters".

Also configoptions[number] are never the same (different on each product page). So I can't target that either.

In short; If the selected radio button with the text "Default anti-spam filters" is selected the DIV should appear.

The order form itself has several different multiple choice options. So targeting the multiple choice by itself won't suffice, I think. I really need to target it's value, as described above.

Sorry for the confusion, but I really try to explain the best I can in English. :|

Comment: What are actually trying to achieve? You question is confusing..

Comment: Something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/07apbnoe/1/)**?

Comment: Yeah the idea is good, however I cannot change (or add) names of the ID's, also the configoptions[number] changes, so I really need to target the value, as in the above example "Default anti-spam filters". Sorry for the confusion; it's kinda hard to explain in English. I did add a follow-up, don't know if that helps though. :(

Comment: so `configoptions` remains same right?

Comment: Sorta; the word "configoptions" stay the same, yes. But not the number behind it. So it could be configoptions[14] for one form and configoptions[49] for the second. Did you mean that?

Comment: I've added answer.. check and let me know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a css-only solution, you can put your additional info in a div (".description") in this example, and show it when the radio button is checked.

```css
.form-group label> .description{
    display:none;
}
.form-group input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .description{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>      
        <input type="radio" name="configoption[14]"  value="43">
    
        No anti-spam solution
        <div class="description">
            Lorem ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
        </div>
  <label>
    
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>      
        <input type="radio" name="configoption[14]"  value="44">
    
        No anti-spam solution
        <div class="description">
            Some other Description
        </div>
  <label>
    
</div>
```

## Edit:

I hope this does what you are looking for, even though it is not a good practice to target the text in the label at all!

```js
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
$label = $.trim($(this).parents('label').text());
  if($label == "No anti-spam solution"){
    $target = $("#noSolution");
  $(".info").not($target).fadeOut();
  $target.fadeIn();
  }else if($label == "Default anti-spam filters"){
    $target = $("#defaultSolution");
  $(".info").not($target).fadeOut();
  $target.fadeIn();
  }
})
```

```css
.additional-info{
position:relative;  
}
.info{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputConfigOption14">
            <div>What kind of anti-spam solution do you want to use</div>
        </label>

        <label class="">
            <div class="iradio_square-blue" style="style="position: relative;">
                <input type="radio" value="43" name="configoption[14] style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></input>
            </div>
            No anti-spam solution
        </label>

        <label class="">
            <div class="iradio_square-blue" style="style="position: relative;">
                <input type="radio" value="43" name="configoption[14] style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></input>
            </div>
            Default anti-spam filters
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Your additional Info divs -->
<div class="additional-info">
<div id="noSolution" class="info">
This is the info for No anti-spam solution!
</div>
<div id="defaultSolution" class="info">
This is the info for Default anti-spam filters!
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot set ID's to this, because it's hard coded in WHMCS. I need to target the value.

Comment: I appreciate the help with this, but I cannot make any text changes anywhere between the labels. It's "hard" coded within WHMCS. So I think I really need to target the text value by jQuery I think? Your solution would obviously work, if I could change the lines in between. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok, where exactly is the additional info that you want to appear after checking the button in the markup?

Comment: It doesn't matter where. I can modify it's location. I just the div to popup when the correct value is selected. Top or bottom of the page, or the location when I can first add a DIV, outside the hardcoded stuff.

Comment: Please check the edit out and let me know if it does what you want.

Comment: Ramtin Gh though your example works (and it does what it's supposed to) it simply doesn't work within my site. No clue why. I appreciate the effort, really. Therefor I am giving you the best answer. Probably I am doing it wrong (somewhere), but this is giving me a headache. I am sorry for your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91590/discussion-between-ramtin-gh-and-hudsonhawk).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `begins with filter` on jquery `selector` as below:

```
$("input[name^='configoption']").on('change',function(){
   $(".alert-info").text($(this).val()).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');
});
//here it will fetch all the inputs whose name attribute begins with "configoption"
//I assume that the name `configoption` will be only given for radio buttons.
```

A point to note in your **html markup**

> In `input type=radio` you haven't closesd `""` after name attribute `name="configoption[14] style="` before writing style.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/07apbnoe/2/)**

Comment: The HTML-part, as posted above, was created / hardcoded by WHMCS, so I cannot change that. It's not my HTML. I just copied it over. I tried your code, however it's now showing the DIV at every other option as well. The above is an example of a single multiple option field. I have several, but for different items. Isn't there a way to target the value of the radio button? If the targeted value is "Default anti-spam filters" it should show that particular (related) DIV, otherwise not. Anyways, thank you so far for your help with this.

Comment: @HudsonHawk Something **[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/07apbnoe/4/)**?

Answer (score 0):

You could set an id for your option and your "banner" so you can handle the "select"-event via jQuery. See example code below.

```js
$('#default-spam').on('click', function() {
  $('#banner').toggle();
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
 <div class="iradio_square-blue">
   <input id="default-spam" type="radio" value="43" name="configoption[14]">
 </div>
 Default anti-spam filters
</label>

<div id="banner" class="hidden">
  Additional information
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot set ID's to this, because it's hard coded in WHMCS. I need to target the value.